# Websphere 8.5 and SpringServletContainerInitializer

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere, servlet-3.0

We have recently converted our app from servlet 2.5 to servlet 3.0 so that we can use dynamic servlet configuration.

We are using Spring's SpringServletContainerInitializer to initialize our application with a corresponding instance of WebApplicationInitializer that lives in our code. This approach works in Tomcat, but when deploying to Websphere 8.5.0.1, the SpringServletContainerInitializer is not able to find the implementation of the WebApplicationInitializer interface in our code, so our Spring MVC dispatcher servlet is not created.

We have found [one blog post](http://incomplete-code.blogspot.com/2013/01/webapplicationinitializer-and-websphere.html) online where the author could not get it to work.

We have tried messing with class loader, class loading orders, and verifying that servlet 3.0 works in the container through other means, and it appears to be OK with that. Using the WAS class loader viewer we can see that the SpringServletContainerInitializer class and WebApplicationInitializer interface are loaded, but not our WebApplicationInitializer implementation.

Has anyone tried this in Websphere? We are thinking it may be a classloader issue but ultimately are clueless.

Comment: Have you tried the WebSphere forum? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000266

Comment: It looks like we might be getting rid of WebSphere. It's cost us weeks of productivity (on issues such as this) and seems to be providing very little value that the organization plans on using.

Comment: I know that this is an old comment however - to have websphere these days if you are not really in some very business and must-certified environment (banks etc.) is absolut useless. It just makes developers slower and also IBM RAD is not helping. Did you solve the problem? I have the same issue when running spring boot + vaadin app in websphere 8.5

Comment: solved the problem by finally convincing folks to move to embedded tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had precisely the same issue.  The problem is a defect in WebSphere fixed by the following APAR http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM85177.  WebSphere builds a cache of annotations & due to the defect when the cache is full it throws away previously cached annotations, resulting in the SpringServletContainerInitializer not finding all implementations of WebApplicationInitializer.

This APAR has already been released in 8.0.0.8 & is scheduled for 8.5.5.2 which is in turn scheduled for April 28th.  In the meantime I managed to increase the size of the cache from it's default of 2000 to 16000 (it failing at 4000 & 8000) at which point my application started working.  One size does not fit all since the cache size is overridden by a system property on the JVM for a WebSphere node the appropriate size will depend on what applications are running on that node & how they (& their JARs) use annotations, so it will be important to play with this setting until the correct value for your application(s) is determined.

The JVM system property I used is -Dclassinfocachesize=16000

Answer (score 3):

I just saw this posting.  When debugging classloader issues WebSphere provides tracing which, when enabled, can give more detail about what is or is not going on.  It is provided in a mustgather data which IBM Support would request if you opened a PMR.  But it is easy enough to read and understand the output.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21196187#show-hide
under "Collecting Data Manually" the trace string to use is

com.ibm.ws.classloader.*=all